# Can't get the session in constructor

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using `$this->id = $this->get('session')->get('id');` in my `__construct()` method and I get this error:

> Call to a member function get() on null

I also tried it with `$this->id = $this->container->get('session')->get('id');` but I get the same error.

The code will work if I use it in another method but not in `__construct()`.

This is how the code looks like:

```
class ProfileDao extends AbstractController {
    private $id;
    private $em;

    function __construct() {
        $this->id = $this->get('session')->get('id');
        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a full example of your code?

Comment: @NicoHaase sure, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions [`ControllerTrait::get($id)`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f531ef57e094c5f4f59b0bd31d7980248ff5259a/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L64) (to fetch a service) as well as [`ControllerTrait::getDoctrine()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f531ef57e094c5f4f59b0bd31d7980248ff5259a/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php#L342) (to fetch doctrine, which is also a service) are both done by accessing the container (see refs in case of doubt), which is set on `AbstractController` via [`AbstractController::setContainer($container)`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f531ef57e094c5f4f59b0bd31d7980248ff5259a/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php#L50) **after it has been created** (this used to be done because it implemented `ContainerAwareInterface`, which signaled to symfony's dependency injection component, it should get a container set, I don't know why/when this is done now... tbh).

And since a non-static method on an object (the [`AbstractController`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f531ef57e094c5f4f59b0bd31d7980248ff5259a/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php) in this case) can only be called (from the outside) after the object has been created from its constructor, and since `setContainer` is a non-static method on an object, the `AbstractController` only can have a container after the constructor is done, but not while the constructor is running.

So that is the reason why those both method calls don't work.

The *solution* to your problem is quite simple, because what absolutely works is properly dependency injecting the classes you need:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class ProfileDao extends AbstractController {
    private $id;
    private $em;

    function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, SessionInterface $session) {
        $this->id = $session->get('id');
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

In general, I avoid the container, because it absolutely *hides* the dependencies a controller has. Some dependencies I tend to use without injecting them explicitly (usually Twig and some HttpKernel/HttpFoundation stuff) because they are very commonly found/used in Controllers.

Comment: Great answer. That helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, even if I like the one about autowiring better: have you checked whether the parent constructor is of any help? If you extend a class (like you're doing with `extends AbstractController`), you should not forget calling `parent::__construct()`, maybe as the first thing in your own `construct` method. This ensures that everything that the parent class needs to work properly is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

This solution dosen't work in Symfony 6.x
I tested below solution in my Symfony 6.1 project.
At the my project I stored my default language in session as "lang"

```
private $lang;

public function __construct()
{
    $session = new Session(); //use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
    $this->lang = $session->get('lang');
}
```

How you can $lnag value in whole your controler ?

```
public function index(): Response
{
    echo $this->lang;
    return ...
}
```